# how to add 3d image to mediapipe pose as a render

Tags: javascript, 3d, mediapipe

I'm just using the bare code of mediapipe pose:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/camera_utils/camera_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils/control_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils_3d/control_utils_3d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/drawing_utils/drawing_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/pose/pose.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <video class="input_video"></video>
    <canvas class="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
    <div class="landmark-grid-container"></div>
  </div>

<script type="module">
const videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];
const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
const landmarkContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('landmark-grid-container')[0];
const grid = new LandmarkGrid(landmarkContainer);

function onResults(results) {
  if (!results.poseLandmarks) {
    grid.updateLandmarks([]);
    return;
  }

  canvasCtx.save();
  canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0,
                      canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  // Only overwrite existing pixels.
  canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
  canvasCtx.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
  canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  // Only overwrite missing pixels.
  canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
  canvasCtx.drawImage(
      results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  drawConnectors(canvasCtx, results.poseLandmarks, POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                 {color: '#00FF00', lineWidth: 4});
  drawLandmarks(canvasCtx, results.poseLandmarks,
                {color: '#FF0000', lineWidth: 2});
  canvasCtx.restore();

  grid.updateLandmarks(results.poseWorldLandmarks);
}

const pose = new Pose({locateFile: (file) => {
  return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/pose/${file}`;
}});
pose.setOptions({
  modelComplexity: 1,
  smoothLandmarks: true,
  enableSegmentation: true,
  smoothSegmentation: true,
  minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
  minTrackingConfidence: 0.5
});
pose.onResults(onResults);

const camera = new Camera(videoElement, {
  onFrame: async () => {
    await pose.send({image: videoElement});
  },
  width: 1280,
  height: 720
});
camera.start();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to render as a filter like snapchat but to whole body.
here are some references to it: https://youtu.be/NL5NHq6tKLM?t=111  <- want something like that

and some useful link:https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose.html

iif you can send me some useful links or videos also that would be great